# How to make subprocess & migration_lookup plugins behave consistently with single and multiple items arrays

Tags: 8, migrations

I have a JSON that can hold single or multi values arrays and I can't make subprocess + migration_lookup behave consistently. It correctly imports the nodes in all cases, but it adds the reference to the imported nodes (entity reference field) only when I have more than 1 item in my array.

my JSON can looks like this:

```
"behaviour": [
          {
            "name": "behaviour name",
            "description": "behaviour description"
          }
        ]
```

or like this:

```
"behaviour": [
          {
            "name": "behaviour name",
            "description": "behaviour description"
          },
          {
            "name": "another behaviour name",
            "description": "another behaviour description"
          }
        ]
```

the process part of my migration config:

```
  field_behaviour:
    plugin: sub_process
    source: behaviour_array
    process:
      target_id:
        plugin: migration_lookup
        migration: import_behaviours_json
        source: name
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just guessing, but you could try forcing the multiple flag on the source field using the [multiple_value](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/migrate_plus/blob/HEAD/src/Plugin/migrate/process/MultipleValues.php) plugin from Migrate Plus:

```
field_behaviour:
  -  
    plugin: multiple_values
    source: behaviour_array
  -  
    plugin: sub_process
    process:
      target_id:
        plugin: migration_lookup
        migration: import_behaviours_json
        source: name
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to fix the issue. BTW, sub process already seems to handle values as multiple.

Answer (score 0):

It urned out the issue was related with migrate_source_jsonpath (the modules used to grab data from JSON).

migrate_source_jsonpath was the one returning single items as strings instead of array.